# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'organizations.leader' in 'where clause'

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I made this code where after I type a command it updates a database. In the last query, the database thinks there's no column named leader in the organizations table, but there is (the query above uses it). What's wrong?
I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0.

```
mp.events.addCommand("organizations", (player, _, abb, namee, hqID) => {
const socialID = player.rgscId;
con.query("SELECT orgID FROM players WHERE scID = "+socialID+"", function (err, result) {
    resultado = result[0].orgID
    if (!abb) {
        // not relevant
    }
    else {
        con.query("SELECT playerID FROM players WHERE scID = "+socialID+"", function (err, result) {
            leaderID = result[0].playerID
            con.query("INSERT INTO organizations (abb, namee, leader, hqID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [abb, namee, leaderID, hqID], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    //not relevant
                }
            });
            con.query("UPDATE players SET player.orgID = organizations.orgID WHERE players.playerID = organizations.leader", function (err, result) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
            });
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE players, organizations
SET player.orgID = organizations.orgID 
WHERE players.playerID = organizations.leader
```